# Implementation dependent code in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, racket, language-features

In `Common Lisp`, when I want to use different pieces of code depending on `Common Lisp` implementations, I can use `*features*` and the provided notation of `#+` and `#-` to check the availability of a given feature and proceed accordingly. So for example (taken from Peter Seibel's PCL):

```
(defun foo ()
  #+allegro (do-one-thing)
  #+sbcl (do-another-thing)
  #+clisp (something-else)
  #+cmu (yet-another-version)
  #-(or allegro sbcl clisp cmu) (error "Not implemented"))
```

Is anyone aware of a similar mechanism for Scheme? There are sometimes subtle differences between different implementations of Scheme, which, when you're trying to be portable, would be nice to abstract away. One such case that comes to my mind is `Racket` not providing mutable pairs by default. Instead of writing e.g. `(set-cdr! lst '(1 2 3))` you would have to use `set-mcdr!` and only after you ran `(require racket/mpair)`. Of course, such things could be abstracted by functions and/or macros, but I think the `Common Lisp` approach is neat in this aspect.

Comment: Scheme has *several standard specifications*, the most common ones being *R5RS*, [*R6RS*](http://www.r6rs.org/), *R7RS*. Choose the one you want to ask about, and study it *before* asking.

Comment: On Racket, `set-mcdr!` only works on a *completely separate data structure* which is not the one supported by `map`, `foldl`, `filter`, or basically any of the functions in the library that expect a list. Racket's runtime library supports *immutable lists only.*

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million You mean in Racket language which isn't Scheme. Rackets rnrs-implementations supports mutable pairs just fine.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million, that's right what you're pointing out, but really the core of the question was the mechanism to distinguish implementations.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing there is, is `cond-expand` (aka SRFI 0), which is available on some Schemes but not others (Racket, for example, doesn't have it, and your code won't compile if you try to use it). For those Schemes that do have it, it looks like a `cond` form, except you test for booleans that tell you things about the compiler/interpreter. On some Schemes you can detect which Scheme you're running on, while on others you can only check for SRFIs:

```
(cond-expand (chicken
              'bok-bok-bok!)
             ((and guile srfi-3432)
              'this-guile-is-full-of-SRFI!)
             (else
              '(might be MIT Scheme, whose cond-expand only tests for SRFIs)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this practically answers my question. I found an implementation of `cond-expand` for Racket [here](http://users.racket-lang.narkive.com/Q0mqlEqb/plt-scheme-srfi-0-cond-expand), but as it is, it can only make Racket fit the `else` branch, which might not be enough.

Comment: @WojciechGac You have [SRFI-7](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-7/) too. AFAIK Racket has it on their list of implemented SRFIs.

Comment: Thanks @Sylwester, I'll have a look.